# юзербот в дс читает только личные сообщения

Tags: python, discord.py

дело в том что я где-то полгода назад делал точно такого же юзербота, и все работало, он мог читать сообщения на серверах и что-то возращать. Сейчас я снова решил сделать юзербота, но бот работает только в личных сообщениях, я уже много всего перепробовал, но ничего не выходит, так же я пробовал менять версии, я знаю что на 2.0 селфботы и юзерботы уже не работают, поэтому и скачал 1.7.3, раньше я ей и пользовался.

```
    import discord,time,random, pyautogui
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='1', intents=discord.Intents.default())
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('+')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('1grab'):
        scr=pyautogui.screenshot()
        scr.save(r'C:\Users\twined\Desktop\slfbot\scrn.png')
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('scrn.png'))
    

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello")
client.run('token', bot = False)
```

Comment: только при таком коде у меня получилось чтобы юзербот хотябы в лс отвечал

Comment: Скоре всего, вам нужно дать боту необходимые разрешения боту в каналах где он присутствует.

Comment: бот может писать в чат и видеть его тоже, если с аккаунта юзербота зайти то он все может

Comment: а где событие on_message() ?

Comment: Нету, раньше я его не использовал и работал, я попробую что-нибудь щас с ним сделать

Comment: ну вот я сделал с событием on_message() и все равно так же реагирует только на сообщения в личные сообщения

Comment: может теперь с юзерботами по другому никак?